# How to understand the following definition of closed set?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

The set $S$ of subsequential limits always contains all limits of sequences from $S$. Such sets are called $closed \ sets$.

Definition: A set is if, whenever $s_n$ is *convergent* sequence completely contained in $S$, its limit is also contained in $S$

I am confused what does it mean by the sequence contained in $S$. Does it mean all its terms are in the set? But won't the set then be infinite?

Comment: Like the finite set $\{1\}$  ,  the only sequence is the constant sequence $(1,1,1,1....) $ i.e. $s_n =1$ for all$n$

Comment: A sequence in S, or a sequence contained in S, means a sequence whose elements are members of S. In Set Theory an infinite sequence is defined as any function whose domain is $\mathbb N.$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it means all its terms are in the set.

Unless the sequence does not use up only finitely many elements (such as sequence of the digits of a real number), the containing set indeed must be infinite.

I read your first two sentences as:

> - A set $S$ is *closed* if always contains all limits of sequences from $S$.
> - The set of subsequential limitpoints of a sequence is always closed.

And, from your comments, it seems your question really aims for a sequence which has infinitely many subsequential limit points.

For this, consider e.g. $a_n=\sin(n)$ : its set of limitpoints is $[-1,1]$.

Comment: How about $s_n=\frac1n$, which converges, the subsequential limits is only $0$, so how is the entire sequence covered in the set?

Comment: To the O.P.: Covered by WHICH set?